# Top Level Args In Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

To reduce the repeat count for WORKDIR I added top level argument in Dockerfile but it is initializing it to an empty value. When I check the GO_VERSION and OS_VERSION top level args they are perfectly used by the build and publish stage

```
# Top level arguments
ARG GO_VERSION=1.22.0
ARG OS_VERSION=bookworm
ARG WORKDIR=/app/configbay-api

# Build stage
FROM golang:${GO_VERSION}-${OS_VERSION} as build

ARG GOOS=linux
ARG GOARCH=amd64

WORKDIR ${WORKDIR}

COPY go.mod go.sum Makefile ./
RUN make install

COPY . ./

RUN make clean-api && \
    make build-api

# Publish stage
FROM debian:${OS_VERSION}

WORKDIR ${WORKDIR}

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install make -y

COPY --from=build ${WORKDIR}/bin ./bin
COPY --from=build ${WORKDIR}/config ./config
COPY --from=build ${WORKDIR}/Makefile ./Makefile

ENV IS_CONTAINER=true
ENV CONF_PATH=${CONF_PATH}
ENV PORT=${PORT}
ENV DB_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}

CMD ["make", "run-api"]

EXPOSE ${PORT}
```

Thanks for helping from now.